# React navigation v6 does not navigate to a nested screen before viewing that screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-bottom-tab, react-navigation-v6

In a react-native (Expo managed and react-navigation v6)  app I have a navigation structure as follows:

When I want to navigate from the `PayWall` screen to `ListPage` with `navigation.navigate('ListPage')` it throws `The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"ListPage"} was not handled by any navigator.`

But if I manually visit the `ListPage` first, then the navigation with `navigation.navigate('ListPage')` works fine.

```
<NavigationContainer>
   <StartScreenStack navigation={undefined} route={undefined} />
</NavigationContainer>

const startScreenStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
export const StartScreenStack = () => (
    <startScreenStack.Navigator>
      <startScreenStack.Screen name={"Hub"} component={TabNavigator} />
      <libraryStack.Screen name={"PayWall"} component={PayWall} />
    </startScreenStack.Navigator>
);

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
export const TabNavigator = () => (
  <Tab.Navigator>
    <Tab.Screen name={"Home"} component={StartScreen} /> // The app starts at this screen
    <Tab.Screen name={"Library"} component={LibraryStack} />
  </Tab.Navigator>
);

const libraryStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
export const LibraryStack = () => (
   <libraryStack.Navigator>
     <libraryStack.Screen name={"MainLibrary"} component={LibraryScreen} /> // The library tab starts at this screen
     <libraryStack.Screen name={"ListPage"} component={ListScreen} />
  </libraryStack.Navigator>
);
```

Also the  `navigation.navigate('Hub', { screen:"Library",params:{screen:"ListPage"}})` only navigates to the root `startScreen`

and `navigation.navigate('Library', { screen: "ListPage"})` behaves like I mentioned at top

I don't understand this behavior, why does visiting the screen manually result in successful navigation?

Answer (score 0):

**First**: you have a little mess in your setup:

- Don't name components like `startScreenStack` or `libraryStack` with lower case
- The components should be in different order and have different names:

  - LibraryStack (this name is good)
  - BottomTabsNavigator - Tab
  - RootStack - StartScreenStack (root is a common name to be sure what stack is at the top of the app)
  - App - NavigationContainer

**Second**: You were close, but if you want to navigate between this two screens you can do it like this:

```
navigation.navigate('Library', { 
  screen: "ListPage"
})
```

Comment: So the problem is the lowercase names or the hierarchy and nesting?

Comment: Also, why does visiting the screen first, cause successful navigation?  I really doubt that the stack instance name starting with lowercase is the root of the issue.

Comment: I just said it's a messy and because of that it's hard to read your code.

The real problem is that you are navigating to the screen that don't exist in the navigation tree. 

You should navigate to Library stack and then to ListPage screen.

Comment: Yes, and navigating to `Library` and then to `ListPage` has the same issue, and after visiting the screen manually works fine. The code is very clear, There might be a problem in the nesting, but the code itself is clearly showing everything

Comment: I have created simple snack for you how you can acheive it:
https://snack.expo.dev/@mateuszrostkowski/navigating-between-stacks